# Observing UIViewController viewWillAppear / Disappear from an external object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've extracted my `NSFetchedResultsController`'s into a separate object. I'd like to monitor when the view controller appears and disappears so that I can pause and resume the FRC delegate methods to update the tableview with new content. Is this possible without any responsibility from the view controller itself? I.e. I know I could use delegates or notifications, but I am looking for a solution where I don't have to sprinkle code all over the view controllers.

Comment: There is no official mechanism.  You might be able to find some property to observe, but it would be wholly-undocumented and subject to change at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there isn't an official way to do this, so here's what I did.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self.fetchedController willAppear];
}
```

And then handled the necessary logic in there... pretty basic.

Maybe another time I'll post about my `fetchedController`. It's pretty neat: it holds a `UISearchController` (and delegates), 2 data sources (one for the regular view, and one for the search). There's a protocol that the view controller implements (tableView, entity name, context, sort descriptors, configureCell, etc) so I never have to create search controllers, NSFetchedResultsController's, or any of the delegates directly. It's much cleaner than having a god UIViewController superclass.